# How to left join on two tables on just unique ids

Tags: sql

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
color_id | label
---------|------
2        | 0
3        | 0
2        | 0
1        | 0
4        | 1
4        | 1
5        | 0
```

Table 2:

```
color_id
--------
2
1
4
```

I want a query that just gives me results for color_ids that are present in Table 2

So, I wrote:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.color_id = table2.color_id
WHERE table2.color_id IS NOT NULL
```

however, the above gives duplicates as well. Meaning I get

```
2  | 0
2  | 0
1  | 0
4  | 1
4  | 1
```

I don't want the duplicates in the results. I just want unique items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the keyword `Left` (or `Right` or `full`) to a join specifier, you make the join an *outer* join. This means that you get all the rows from one side of the join, and only those rows from the other side that match.  If you only want the rows from `table_1` where the `color_id` is in `table_2`, then you want an *inner* join, specified by writing `inner join` or just writing `join`, without a `left`, `right` or `full`.

to eliminate duplicates, add the keyword `distinct` to the select clause...

```
Select distinct color_id, label
From table1 t1
  join table2 t2
     on t2.color_id = t1.color_id
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want a query that just gives me results for color_ids that are present in Table 2

So, you shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN` in this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.color_id, a.label
FROM table_1 a JOIN table_2 b
ON a.color_id = b.color_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT color_id
FROM table_1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 T2 where T1.color_id = T2.color_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join and a distinct clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.color_id, table1.label
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.color_id = table2.color_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an INNER JOIN combined with a

```
SELECT distinct table1.color_id, tabl1.label
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.color_id = table2.color_id
```

This eliminates any item in table1 not present in table 2 and duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

the reason of that is you used Left Join, which will keep all obs in table1.
Try this:

SELECT table1.* FROM table1 Inner JOIN table2 ON table1.color_id = table2.color_id

this should works as actually all table2 obs are in table1. To be more serious, if table2 has obs that are not in table1 and you do want to keep them, replace **inner join** with **right join**.